# Function to request user claims and token from Identity Server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

What is the best way to retrieve user claims and tokens after logging into identity server?

I have a .Net Core MVC web app. I redirect to an identity server, log in, then redirect back to my web app.

From my app I would then like to request user claims and token from identity server.

Is there a method call to do this?

I have gone through the tutorials and searched around and found libraries (oidc-client-js, oidc.usermanager for javascript that handles this. OidcClient for native c# apps) that handle this behavior, but not for c# web app - so I realize maybe what I'm asking for is not the convention but I'd still appreciate any insight on this.

Edit:

To elaborate, in the c# web app tutorials, specifically tutorial #3, I fail to see how claims and token information become retrievable from from figure 1 to figure 2.

Furthermore, I'm trying to call and handle these objects in c#, not html.

Figure 1

[image: figure 1]

Figure 2

[image: figure 2]

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by `fail to see how claims and token information become retrievable from from figure 1 to figure 2` User.Claims is null after login ?

Comment: UserManager is used to access the Identity tables and is only available in IdentityServer. Clients and Api's don't have access to the IdentityServer database. Instead they request info (on login) from IdentityServer, using scopes and endpoints, like the UserInfo endpoint. After succesful login the client receives an access token that contains the requested info in the form of a claims collection and can be found in User.Identity.

Comment: Read the documentation on how to configure the client: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html#modifying-the-mvc-client

Comment: @NanYu I just didn't see the logical connection between clicking "secure" and suddenly having access to user claims. However, after a day of playing with this, I think I understand the supporting mechanisms better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller , you can retire claims like

```
 var claims = User.Claims;
```

Get the access token/id token/refresh token :

```
 var accessToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;
 var idToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token").Result;
 var refreshToken = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token").Result;
```

To achieve that , you need register your OIDC middleware inside ConfigureServices as follows (making sure to set SaveTokens to true) :

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
// Set all your OIDC options...

// and then set SaveTokens to save tokens to the AuthenticationProperties
options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

In mvc razor page , you can get the information :

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<dl>
    @foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
    {
        <dt>@claim.Type</dt>
        <dd>@claim.Value</dd>
    }

</dl>

<dt>access token</dt>
<dd>@await ViewContext.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")</dd>

<dt>ID token</dt>
<dd>@await ViewContext.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token")</dd>

<dt>refresh token</dt>
<dd>@await ViewContext.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token")</dd>
```